# How to add attribute and also elementString via XmlTextWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextwriter

I am using `XmlTextWriter` to generate the xml file.
Most parts are fine, but encounter the problem to generate bellow part,
What I need is:

`<site isTrue="false">http://www.example.com</site>`

partly main code of mine:

```
...

using System.Xml;

string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\myxml.xml";
     XmlTextWriter myxml = null;
     try
     {
        myxml = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        myxml.WriteStartDocument();
        // 
        // first 
        myxml.WriteElementString("site","http://www.example.com");
        //
        // second 
        //
        myxml.WriteStartElement("site")
        myxml.WriteAttributeString("isTrue", "false");
     }
    ...
```

then, for the first method I try , the result is:

`<site>http://www.example.com</site>`

or if I use second I try ,then the result become:

`<site isTrue="false"></site>`

any method to add attribute and also innertext? As bellow:

`<site isTrue="false">http://www.example.com</site>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myxml.WriteStartElement("site");
myxml.WriteAttributeString("isTrue", "false");
myxml.WriteString("http://www.example.com");
```

Comment: thanks! that's my problem I don't know `WriteString()`
it's difficult if I don't know.
it's easy if it's known. :)